# How to draw a star by using canvas HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Am trying to draw a star using canvas, but the code is not running. I want to understand: what are the steps to measure the Y and X coordinate? How to find them? to draw any shape?

```
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset = "utf-8">
   <title>Drawing Lines</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <canvas id = "drawLines" width = "400" height = "200" 
     style = "border: 1px solid Black;">
   </canvas>
   <script>
     var canvas = document.getElementById("drawLines");
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d")

     canvas.beginPath(); 
     canvas.moveTo(50,50);
     canvas.lineTo(120,150);
     canvas.lineTo(0,180); 
     canvas.lineTo(120,210);
     canvas.lineTo(50,310);  
     canvas.lineTo(160,250);
     canvas.lineTo(190,370);
     canvas.lineTo(220,250);
     canvas.lineTo(330,310);
     canvas.lineTo(260,210);
     canvas.lineTo(380,180);
     canvas.closePath();
     canvas.stroke();
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 44):

A star is basically a regular polygon with alternating points on an inner and an outer radius.

Here's an example of a flexible function to draw a star shape.

You can set the position, #spikes and the inner & outer radius of the spikes:

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8j6kdf4o/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawStar(cx,cy,spikes,outerRadius,innerRadius){
      var rot=Math.PI/2*3;
      var x=cx;
      var y=cy;
      var step=Math.PI/spikes;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
      for(i=0;i<spikes;i++){
        x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*outerRadius;
        y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*outerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x,y)
        rot+=step

        x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*innerRadius;
        y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*innerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x,y)
        rot+=step
      }
      ctx.lineTo(cx,cy-outerRadius);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth=5;
      ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
      ctx.fill();
    }

    drawStar(100,100,5,30,15);

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just did about 3 hours work in about 5 minutes, thanks to you :)

Comment: there is a typo on `ctx.strokeSyle`, it should be `ctx.strokeStyle`

Comment: This is the answer I ended up using. Clean, versatile and bug free.

Comment: Very useful.  The only changes I'd recommend are: a. make strokeStyle and fillStyle parameters; b. i in your for loop is an implicit global, which should really be properly defined.  Overall this is super useful and helpful though.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 15):

The function can be shorter with coordinate translate:

```
function strokeStar(x, y, r, n, inset) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0-r);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / n);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - (r*inset));
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / n);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 0 - r);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: Love this method, can be adapted to anything with rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Those functions, lineTo(), moveTo(), stroke(), etc... belong to the context object, not the canvas object. Are you checking your developer console (f12 in Chrome)? You would see that these functions are undefined.

Comment: Yes am checking the console by Chrome.How to make them defined ?How to write them to be canvas object ?

Answer (score 2):

```
//function to draw star with N spikes
//centered on a circle of radius R, centered on (cX,cY)
function star(R, cX, cY, N) {
  //star draw
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cX + R,cY);
  for(var i = 1; i <= N * 2; i++)
  {
    if(i % 2 == 0){
      var theta = i * (Math.PI * 2) / (N * 2);
      var x = cX + (R * Math.cos(theta));
      var y = cY + (R * Math.sin(theta));
    } else {
      var theta = i * (Math.PI * 2) / (N * 2);
      var x = cX + ((R/2) * Math.cos(theta));
      var y = cY + ((R/2) * Math.sin(theta));
    }

    ctx.lineTo(x ,y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const createStar = ({ points = 5, x = 0, y = 0, size = 10 }) =>
  Array.from({ length: points * 2 }, (_, i, arr) =>
    new DOMMatrix()
      .translate(x, y)
      .scale(size)
      .rotate((i / (points * 2)) * 360)
      .translate(0, i % 2 ? -1 : -2)
      .transformPoint({ x: 0, y: 0 })
  );
  
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();

const shape = createStar({ x: 20, y: 20 });
shape.forEach((c, i) => {
    if(i === 0) { ctx.moveTo(c.x, c.y); } else { ctx.lineTo(c.x, c.y); }
});

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @v-rubinetti, you are trying to call methods incorrectly.

While it can be easy to draw a simple star in canvas by coding, it's complicated for drawing advanced things. You can use a open-source Vector graphics software like [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) along with the [ink2canvas](https://github.com/hacktoon/ink2canvas) extension to draw advanced vector graphics and save them to a html5 document.

For example, here is a 25-pointed Star drawn in Inkscape and saved using ink2canvas extension:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Inkscape Output</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width='320' height='320'></canvas>
    <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    ctx.lineCap = 'butt';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1.000000;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.transform(0.506236, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.505711, 82.274469, 51.410524);
    ctx.moveTo(342.857130, 449.505040);
    ctx.lineTo(234.764940, 344.516400);
    ctx.lineTo(279.468630, 488.419550);
    ctx.lineTo(200.881970, 359.847880);
    ctx.lineTo(208.393950, 510.347410);
    ctx.lineTo(164.250710, 366.271350);
    ctx.lineTo(134.098980, 513.910810);
    ctx.lineTo(127.172840, 363.383190);
    ctx.lineTo(61.251941, 498.885850);
    ctx.lineTo(91.978093, 351.364870);
    ctx.lineTo(-5.569921, 466.216610);
    ctx.lineTo(60.877887, 330.971560);
    ctx.lineTo(-62.167941, 417.955810);
    ctx.lineTo(35.826363, 303.484630);
    ctx.lineTo(-104.985860, 357.135850);
    ctx.lineTo(18.397601, 270.631190);
    ctx.lineTo(-131.333260, 287.578290);
    ctx.lineTo(9.686712, 234.475540);
    ctx.lineTo(-139.554650, 213.653670);
    ctx.lineTo(10.241036, 197.289490);
    ctx.lineTo(-129.133450, 140.006950);
    ctx.lineTo(20.025741, 161.409550);
    ctx.lineTo(-100.724450, 71.265628);
    ctx.lineTo(38.426018, 129.090210);
    ctx.lineTo(-56.112700, 11.748970);
    ctx.lineTo(64.285711, 102.362200);
    ctx.lineTo(1.898679, -34.803371);
    ctx.lineTo(95.979959, 82.904945);
    ctx.lineTo(69.664621, -65.466342);
    ctx.lineTo(131.517300, 71.941014);
    ctx.lineTo(142.927140, -78.313274);
    ctx.lineTo(168.664780, 70.159311);
    ctx.lineTo(217.082890, -72.536949);
    ctx.lineTo(205.088300, 77.671789);
    ctx.lineTo(287.472380, -48.500313);
    ctx.lineTo(238.499240, 94.006409);
    ctx.lineTo(349.672790, -7.713676);
    ctx.lineTo(266.798250, 118.136810);
    ctx.lineTo(399.775840, 47.260185);
    ctx.lineTo(288.207210, 148.546780);
    ctx.lineTo(434.633360, 112.967060);
    ctx.lineTo(301.380910, 183.325570);
    ctx.lineTo(452.055130, 185.278350);
    ctx.lineTo(305.491610, 220.287880);
    ctx.lineTo(450.946490, 259.650470);
    ctx.lineTo(300.281000, 257.111240);
    ctx.lineTo(431.377070, 331.410340);
    ctx.lineTo(286.076510, 291.481900);
    ctx.lineTo(394.576520, 396.049020);
    ctx.lineTo(263.770630, 321.240230);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you convert your SVG file into codes when you can simply draw from a SVG file: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq6rksct/1 Hard coding data into your code is considered a bad practice.

Comment: How else can I answer the question about the context methods? I am not taking sides in the Canvas vs SVG debate. Pick the one that works the best for you for what you are doing (For example, for games, canvas works best).

Comment: You might want to re-read my comment. I did not even say anything about using SVG over canvas.

Comment: Does not answer the question. Looking to "measure the x and y" and "draw any shape". Some calculation should be being done for this to be a relevant answer.

Comment: LOL. kums you r and id***t.