# How can I transform grouped canvas elements on click?

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

Say I have a simple canvas element like this:
HTML:

```js
function oval(context, x, y, w, h)
{
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.scale(w/2, h/2);
    context.arc(1, 1, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    context.closePath();
    context.restore();
}

function drawCanvas(canvasId)
{
    //// General Declarations
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    //// Color Declarations
    var blackColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
    var color = 'rgba(0, 109, 73, 1)';
    var color2 = 'rgba(255, 255, 87, 1)';

    //// Group
    //// Oval Drawing
    oval(context, 76.5, 64.5, 47, 47);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = blackColor;
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();


    //// Star Drawing
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 74.5);
    context.lineTo(104.76, 81.45);
    context.lineTo(112.84, 83.83);
    context.lineTo(107.7, 90.5);
    context.lineTo(107.94, 98.92);
    context.lineTo(100, 96.1);
    context.lineTo(92.06, 98.92);
    context.lineTo(92.3, 90.5);
    context.lineTo(87.16, 83.83);
    context.lineTo(95.24, 81.45);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = color2;
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = blackColor;
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/canvas.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        drawCanvas('mainCanvas');
    };
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point I have the two shape in defined separately in the canvas element.  I would like to be able to have the two items move as one (as if it were a ball with a star on it) when clicked.  I see that `transform` is supported by canvas.  Is that the best way to have canvas elements move from a click?

Comment: Just wrap both paths in another save/restore and add the transform you want for both of them, That way the first transform will move both paths and the second transform will still move the relative amount you wanted.

Comment: @Blindman67 do you mind giving me a code example of your comment?  I am new to working with `canvas` elements so a simple code output would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Blindman67 has the correct idea: Draw both the circle and the star at the same time -- thus creating a group.

The only bump in your code is that you've hardcoded the star coordinates. To use the hardcoded coordinates, you can "normalize" the star coordinates so that the star is centered at [0,0]. The `context.translate(x,y)` method will move the canvas origin [0,0] to x,y -- effectively moving your star's centerpoint to the canvas [0,0]. If you want to learn how to draw a star using relative coordinates (rather than hardcoded coordinates) then check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837158/how-to-draw-a-star-by-using-canvas-html5/25840319#25840319).

**Here is example code and a demo that animates your group in a circle**

*You can use the `drawGroup` function in the code to draw your group at any x,y*

```js
//// General Declarations
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

//// Color Declarations
var blackColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
var color = 'rgba(0, 109, 73, 1)';
var color2 = 'rgba(255, 255, 87, 1)';

//
var centerX=150;
var centerY=150;
var radius=20;
var animationRadius=50;
var animationAngle=0;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    var x=centerX+animationRadius*Math.cos(animationAngle);
    var y=centerY+animationRadius*Math.sin(animationAngle);
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    drawGroup(x,y,radius);
    animationAngle+=Math.PI/60;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function drawGroup(centerX,centerY,radius){
    // Oval
    oval(centerX,centerY,radius);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = blackColor;
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
    // star
    star(centerX,centerY,radius);
    context.fillStyle = color2;
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = blackColor;
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
}
      
function oval(x,y,r){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.closePath();
}

function star(x,y,r){
    var w=112.84-87.16;
    var h=98.92-74.5;
    // normalize fixed star coordinates by moving
    //    the center of the star to [0,0] with context.translate
    context.translate(-87.16-w/2,-74.5-h/2);
    // now move to x,y
    context.translate(x,y);
    // draw the star
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100,    74.5);
    context.lineTo(104.76, 81.45);
    context.lineTo(112.84, 83.83);
    context.lineTo(107.7,  90.5);
    context.lineTo(107.94, 98.92);
    context.lineTo(100,    96.1);
    context.lineTo(92.06,  98.92);
    context.lineTo(92.3,   90.5);
    context.lineTo(87.16,  83.83);
    context.lineTo(95.24,  81.45);
    context.closePath();
    // always clean up, reverse the translate
    context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as pointed out in comments wrap transforms in save/restore pairs as these will store state of canvas including current transformation matrix in the same way a stack would (push/pop) - (pseudo):

```
ctx.save();
  ctx.transform(..);   // transform context
  // draw something
  ctx.save();
    ctx.transform(..); // transform context again
    // draw something relative to previous transform
  ctx.restore();       // we're back to first transform
ctx.restore();         // we're back to original transform
```

In this case though you would probably just use the outer save/restore pair.

The other way is to store the paths in Path2D objects. These can be reused and you can transform context before filling/stroking them:

```
var p = new Path2D();
p.moveTo(x, y);
p.lineTo(x, y);
// ... etc.
```

Then:

```
ctx.transform(x, y);  // some transform
ctx.fill(p);          // fill path
```

You may need to define several paths if the shape has several colors etc. The benefit with this method is slightly more performance as you only need to define the shape once for each part.

Third way is to draw your paths onto an off-screen canvas, then draw the canvas as an image back on your main canvas using a simple x/y offset and without the need for transforms. This is the fastest method but require you to store a bitmap (in this case it should not have any noticeable impact).

To make an off-screen canvas:

```
var oc = document.createElement("canvas");
var oCtx = oc.getContext("2d");
oc.width = someSizeMatchingShapeWidth;
oc.height = someSizeMatchingShapeHeight;

// draw path once into canvas `oc` uing `oCtx` for context
```

Then for your main canvas:

```
context.drawImage(oc, x, y);
```